# Problem with parameter to Swift Process object

Tags: swift

I am working on a GUI for rclone (and rsync) and utilizing the Process object for executing remote commands. It works very well, but now I have an issue which I am not able to solve.

The arguments to the Process object is an array of Strings. The following command works as expected when pasting the command in a terminal window.

```
/usr/bin/rclone sync /Users/thomas/test/source local:/Users/thomas/test/dest --verbose --backup-dir=local:/Users/thomas/test/dest_backup --suffix=`date "+-%Y-%m-%d"`
```

The problem is the last argument: `` --suffix=`date "+-%Y-%m-%d"` ``.

The argument (when pasting the command in a terminal) adds a date suffix for deleted and changed files.

The string of arguments in Swift is:

```
arguments = [....
    "--verbose",
    "--backup-dir=local:/Users/thomas/test/dest_backup",
    "--suffix=`date \"+-%Y-%m-%d\"`"]
```

And the result is that the suffix on backed up files becomes the string and not the date when executing.

The Process object does not execute the date command...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the documentation states clearly that shell expansions are not resolved:

> The strings in arguments do not undergo shell expansion, so you do not need to do special quoting, and shell variables, such as $PWD, are not resolved.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1408983-arguments

So what you are trying to do cannot be done that way.

Have you tried to embed a small shell script, let's say `run.sh` with its own `#!/bin/sh` and your command line, and run it with the `Process` object?

Comment: Hmm, thx - did not know about this limitations, Passing shell commands in swift to rsync works, rsync expands the shell command on the remote server.. adding this string  --suffix=_`date +'%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M'` as an argument in Swift works on remote computers but not if the destination is a local attached volume on macOS..

Answer (score 0):

As [Zaphod said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976280/1187415), no shell expansion is done on the arguments, so that in particular

```
--suffix=`date "+-%Y-%m-%d"`
```

is passed verbatim to the rclone command, without evaluating the command between the backticks first.

But you can compute the argument using `DateFormatter` instead:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "-yyyy-MM-dd"
let dateSuffix = formatter.string(from: Date()) // -2018-12-30

let arguments = [ // ....
    "--verbose",
    "--backup-dir=local:/Users/thomas/test/dest_backup",
    "--suffix=\(dateSuffix)" ]
```

Comment: Thx, I will see if I can compute the date string ahead of execution. The problem though is that the parameter is user selected. I might compute the date when the app (https://github.com/rsyncOSX/rcloneosx) is loaded. I have another GUI for rsync (https://github.com/rsyncOSX/RsyncOSX). The date suffix to rsync is expanded on the remote computer. I suppose rclone expand the parameter on the local OS and  then transfer the suffix to the cloud service...